# 'Unable to mount New Volume' and 'Unable to mount 202 GB Filesystem' in Ubuntu 12.04.2

Tags: boot, partitioning, usb, mount, usb-drive

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.2 on a live usb,

After I restarted my system with bootable usb, when I try to open my harddisk, it shows--

`Unable to mount New Volume`
`Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 21: mount: according to mtab, /dev/sda3 is already mounted on /media/New Volume.`

And

`Unable to mount 202 GB Filesystem`
`Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 21: mount: according to mtab, /dev/sda2 is already mounted on /media/AECE2545CE250765`

and i am not even able to access my pendrives, I have some really important programs stored in live USB and i want to copy and paste it in the harddisk. 
Please help...Thanks in advance

Comment: So your hard disk's sda2 and sda3 partitions are already mounted. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely that your USB-drive is now detected as the `/dev/sda` device, as it is the first device found during the boot-up.

Try running `sudo lshw -c disk` in a terminal. There you will find that your harddisk is probably `/dev/sdb` at this point. Then run `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb` and see if you recognize the partition sizes and layout. If that is the disk, then you should be able to mount it the way you already did, but change the `sda` to `sdb` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you use both windows 8 and Ubuntu and you cant access win8 partitions from Ubuntu, just boot into win8, open Command prompt and type this:

```
powercfg -h off
```

And the problem will be solved.